# Another "id cannot be resolved or is not a field", but this is different

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Long story made short:

I had a few problems working on my MP3 Player for a Finals Project. 
Eclipse didn't generate a R.java file on my project, so i created a new one.
I declare all the layout, id, drawable and the buttons i have.
This "id cannot be resolved or is not a field" wasn't a problem a few moments before, Quick Fix *Fixed* (Duh!) it for me creating a field in my R.Java file in the **gen** folder.

But the thing i have this code:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.id.playlist);
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Harmless code~~~~~~~~~~

```
  // Add menuItems to ListView
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, songsListData,
            R.layout.playlist_item, new String[] { "songTitle" }, new int[] {
                    R.id.songTitle });
```

Both *R.**layout**.playlist* and *R.**id**.songTitle* are supposed to be declared on my R.Java.

Any Help Here?

Comment: R.java is **NOT** to be even edited ! try change the computer amd ADT download file to rule out any bugs

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing `R.layout.playlist_item` in your list adapter. Are you sure `R.layout.playlist_item` exists? Have you tried doing Project > Clean in Eclipse?

Comment: Every time i Clean the Project, R.Java is deleted and i have to restore it

Comment: Have you read through this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error)? I've run into issues related to R.java because I often do a ctrl-shift-O to add imports. There was one time Eclipse mistakenly added a `import android.R`, which will throw everything off.

Comment: i've aslo read about that issue, and i had no "import android.R" on my entire Projct